# What is the relative URL for https://example.com//path?

Tags: url

What is the relative (to https://example.com) URL for "https://example.com//path"?

It's not "//path" as that's an absolute URL.

Comment: Relative to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

the absolute URL is /path

https://example.com//path is the same as https://example.com/path

Comment: Got a reference for that?

Comment: no need reference for that if // would exist it would mean / separate / by empty folder. empty foldername doesnot exist

Comment: Only if path is mapped to a filesystem location

Comment: A web app may contain code equivalent to `if (path == "/f") return p_f(); else return p_not_found();` In this case `/`' and `//f` are clearly not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path is indeed `https://example.com//path`, it's called absolute because you don't need any thing else to navigate to that url, unlike the relative urls, which are usually relative to the root of the document, like in your case `/path`

A relative URL will always refer back to the domain it's on,
so if you're on `http://example.com` then `/path` will redirect to `http://example.com/path`
and if you move your app to `http://example2.com` then the url will redirect to `http://example2.com/path`

The double slash is a mistake, but most of the time the web servers fix that error and redirect you back to the correct url, like for example
https://stackoverflow.com/////a//////28782401/////2149092 which will redirect you back to this same answer.

Comment: Got a reference for the double slash bit?